# What does this error mean? Pygame Error: Font Not Initialized

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am currently making a small game but it is showing a strange error message. Namely:

```
'Pygame Error': Font Not Initialized
```

What does this mean?

This is my code:

```
import pygame, random, sys, os, time
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
WINDOWWIDTH = 800
WINDOWHEIGHT = 600
levens = 3
dead = False
Mousevisible = False

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def waitForPlayerToPressKey():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE: #escape quits
                    terminate()
                return

def drawText(text, font, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, TEXTCOLOR)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)
#fonts
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)

#def gameover():
    #if dead == True:
        #pygame.quit

# set up pygame, the window, and the mouse cursor
pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('hit the blocks')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(Mousevisible)

# "Start" screen
drawText('Press any key to start the game.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 30, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
drawText('And Enjoy', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3)+30)
pygame.display.update()
waitForPlayerToPressKey()
zero=0
```

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\flori\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\schietspel.py", line 30, in <module>
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)
  File "C:\Users\flori\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pygame\sysfont.py", line 320, in SysFont
    return constructor(fontname, size, set_bold, set_italic)
  File "C:\Users\flori\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pygame\sysfont.py", line 243, in font_constructor
    font = pygame.font.Font(fontpath, size)
pygame.error: font not initialized
```

Comment: We can't help you if you don't provide your code (or relevant parts of it).

Comment: always put full error message (full Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information. it should show you in which line of code you have problem.

Comment: show your code - we can't read in your mind.

Comment: at start you should use `Google` to find more information about `'Pygame Error': Font Not Initialized`. Maybe someone already had this problem and he resolved it. This way you could have answer few hours ago.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that you're setting the font before initializing the game. To fix this, move `font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)` after `pygame.init()`.

Also, for your code to work, you'll need to define `TEXTCOLOR` as well. It should be a tuple with RGB values eg. `TEXTCOLOR = (255, 255, 255)` for white (you can put it at the top with the `WINDOWHEIGHT`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to initialize pygame.font.

Try `pygame.font.init()` after `from pygame.locals import *`

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding `pygame.init()` before `pygame.font.Font()` fixed the problem.